# listviewbeforefilter event not firing on filterable list after upgrading to JQM 1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

We're currently updating jQuery Mobile from 1.3 to 1.4 and as expected there have been a few hiccups along the way. One particularly frustrating issue is that the listviewbeforefilter event on a filterable list is not firing.

The listview element used is `<ul id="search-orders" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search orders..."></ul>`, and the change event is being called like:

```
$('#search-orders').on('listviewbeforefilter', function ( e, data ) {
    // ... do some stuff ...
});
```

I can provide more detail about what's actually happening in the event, but since it's not even being fired in 1.4 (and works as expected in 1.3), I don't think the implementation is the issue. Did something change in how the event works or how to attach it to the filterable list? I've checked the documentation and examples and can't figure out what would have changed here to have broken this.

Comment: Great I wanted to know what the filterablebeforefilter equivalent is in v1.3 and you question gave me the answer: listviewbeforefilter. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using filterablebeforefilter.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/VPXvN/)**

```
$(document).on( 'pagecreate', '#page1',function(){
    $('#search-orders').on('filterablebeforefilter' ,function ( e, data ){
        alert('before filter');
    });
});
```